# c# run 2 (or more) process in different timing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, process

how to run different tasks in different process?

in my case I will have 2 tasks one runs every 1 mint the other will run every 10 mints

the point is each one is totally independent from the other

how to make them work within the same program?

Comment: So "within the same program" but "in different process[es]"? Can you clarify what you have and what you need?

Comment: my program will have kind of a timer that will run a function, so I will have to timers with different timing that runs 2 different functions in my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd do it is to create a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28VS.80%29.aspx) that contains a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28VS.71%29.aspx).  The [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28VS.71%29.aspx) checks at regular intervals if it is time to run each process, and when it is time to run starts each process using either

1. The [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28VS.80%29.aspx) class (if that's what I think you meant by different processes)
2. A new [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) itself.  You will have to have each function that needs to run compiled into a seperate executable and then you simply start it using this class.

Hope that helps!

Comment: what about BackgroundWorker do I need to take a look at it?

Comment: @Data-Base: Thats another option, although the Background Worker's designed for running a time consuming process in the background so that you can keep the UI responsive. Personally I'd go with the ThreadPool but have a read here for an example of the two: http://olivercode.net/2010/02/22/threading-with-the-thread-pool/

Comment: Thanks allot :-) ThreadPool seems easy :-)  my app is a GUI and each of my functions will run a process (which is an external program), so hmmmmmm

Comment: @Data-Base: In that case why not use the ThreadPool to start each process in a new Process http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx and get each process to WaitForExit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4b407xt.aspx so you can tell if it is still running or not